# Responsive element in my website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i know this question will be easy for a lot of people, but for me is not, especially i'm not front-end developer and i have a project for my university that depends fully on back-end and have a simple front-end code.
i have 2 buttons below 2 green boxes, those buttons supposed to be at the middle of the green boxes, at my small screen of my PC, everything works fine and they locate at the middle of my screen like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnfnl.png)

but if i used the computer at my university, which will be used at discussion with my prof, the shape will be completely different like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3NYS.png)
see how the buttons moved away because the code website is not responsive ?
and here is css code for my buttons

```
.spots .spot button{
  background-color: white; 
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:absolute;
}
.spots .spot button:hover{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
.spots .spot #park1button{
  top:1700px;
  left:130px;
}
.spots .spot #park2button{
  top:1700px;
  left:370px;
}
```

the html Code:

```
<div class="normal spot">
    <h2>For Daily Customers</h2>
    <div id="park1"class="colorofback">
      <p id="park1p">spot number 1 is available</p>
    </div>
    <div id="park2" class="colorofback">
      <p id="park2p">spot number 2 is available</p>
    </div>
    <button id="park1button">click to book</button>
    <button id="park2button">click to book</button>
</div>
```

and finally the css code for containers of 2 buttons

```
.spots{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
.spots h1{
  color:Teal;
  text-align:center;
}
.spots .spot{
  width:48%;
  float:left;
  padding:7px;
}
.spots .normal{
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
.spots .spot h2{
  color:#696969;
  text-align:center;
}
.spots .spot .colorofback{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left:25px;
  margin-right:10px;
  float:left;
  padding:2px;
}
.spots .spot .colorofback p{
  text-align: center;
  padding:8px;
}
```

so how can the button be displayed always at the middle below the 2 green boxes, even i change the size of my screen ?

Comment: don't use fixed value .. use % values instead

Comment: You might want to just put a div around all of it and give it `margin: auto;` to center it horizontally. For more advanced layout I suggest looking into [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and/or [grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try flex property, it's super comfortable to work with unless your project will run on some old browsers.
I'm your case you have used the position: absolute css property which will absolutely position your DOM element based on the top and left values. And I guess that's the reason. Remove the position absolute property. Never use that unless it's necessary. The need of this property is totally different and should be used only if you want to place something adjecent to another Dom  (ex: drop down) also the structure of your html can be improved. Based on the preview I would suggest you to put the spot available div and the respective button inside a single div. Do this for both and add align:center attribute for the parent div. This will center align everything vertically and won't break when the screen size changes.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend flex for an easy way out just yet. I have built stuff on flex and it's simply too unstable. Edge, Firefox and Chrome all handle flex differently. Besides, it still has some issues where it's extremely hard to get the other elements within the container right. 1 character too much or too little can break a flex container. It can add odd paddings and margins or create random white space between child elements... I'd say it's fine to use it just for single elements and aligning those. However, it's not trustworthy for nesting just yet. Modern browsers included.